# Trying to make a function that copies the content of one file and writes it to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question that states
**Write a function fcopy() that takes as input two file names (as strings) and copies the content of the first file into the second.**
and I want to know how to go about solving this.

My first file is named example, and the second file is named output, both text files are in .txt format, and the path to them are 
*"C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\Introduction to Computing\Lab\assignments\example.txt"*
and *"C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\Introduction to Computing\Lab\assignments\output.txt"*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Homework questions should show effort and the current code that you have. You are unlikely to get a good response by dumping your homework question verbatim; explain what you're struggling with and provide clear debugging information.

Comment: That would require really simply Python IO. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

You are not to ask StackOverflow to do your homework for you. Feeling generous though...

First of all, read this: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/shutil.html It's the Python 3 docs for the shutil module. It will give high-level functions for reading/writing files (I/O).

```
from shutil import copyfile
copyfile(locationOfSource, locationOfDestination)
```

An important thing to note is that "\" (back-slash) signifies non-literal text, so "\n" means new line, NOT just "\n". This is rarely mentioned and had me stumped when I first learnt escape characters. To do the back-slash that you want within a string, you MUST use "\" instead of "\".

The commenters below your answer are correct, please read the information given to you by StackOverflow about asking questions. Also, welcome to the site.

Comment: so far, coding has gone to this, and I still can't seem to get it to work

Comment: def fcopy(file1, file2):
    os.chdir('C:/Users/HOME/Desktop/Introduction to Computing/Lab/assignments')
    open_file_1 = open(file1, 'r')
    open_file_2 = open(file2, 'w')
    for line in open_file_1:
        open_file_2.write(line)
    open_file_1.close()
    open_file_2.close()
    open_file_2 = open(file2, 'r')
    for line in open_file_2:
        print(line)
    open_file_2.close()

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to, you could write a simple wrapper function to accomplish this:

```
def copy_file(orig_file_name, copy_file_name):
    with open(orig_file_name, 'r') as orig_file, open(copy_file_name, 'w+') as cpy_file:
        orig_file = orig_file.read()
        cpy_file.write(orig_file)
```

But as @Frogboxe has already said, the correct way to copy a file is to used the shutil library:

```
import shutil
shutil.copy(target_file, copy_file)
```

Comment: upvoted. A very Pythonic way of doing IO. Granted, this is more for when some manipulation is going on, but newbies to Python never seem to be taught the "with" and "open" key words which are great for handling streams.

Comment: @Frogboxe Thanks man, appreciate it. Yeah though, many novices to python never learn proper IO. in fact, I did Python for months before fully understanding proper IO.